# Respect users' default background color on text edit areas

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I recently changed my GTK theme to [zenburn](http://deletionpedia.dbatley.com/w/index.php?title=Zenburn) and noticed that while on meta.stackoverflow the background color is preserved:

[image: meta.stackoverflow]

This is not true for meta.android.stackexchange.com and android.stackexchange.com however, only the foreground text color from the theme is used while the background is fixed white:

[image: meta.android].

Note that this is with Firefox, Chrome doesn't show this behavior.

Comment: Site-specific issues need to stay here rather than go to MSO.  I'll see if I can poke someone to look at this though.

Comment: There's also no way to migrate meta posts.... You could try posting to MSO too if you feel it's a site-wide issue (I'm sure other sites have issues too).

Comment: @BryanDenny This seems to be an AN.SX issue. Other sites of the SX network don't have the issue. At least I couln't reproduce it on other sites.

Comment: Grace is going to poke Jin (the designer), but apparently he's swamped so hopefully you can muster up a bit more patience :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed and should be pushed out in the next deployment.